# In C++, casting to subclasses for overloaded functions?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, overloading

So here's the situation:

I have an abstract superclass "model" for a raytracer program, from which various kind of geometry inherit properties and functions. There will be no objects of type model, obviously, but there will be an array of type model in which the entire geometry of the scene will be stored.

Then a number of Rays will be cast by the raytracer. Each ray will iterate through this array of models and check if it collides with them using its own method, Ray::intersect. Thus, Ray's declaration includes approximately this:

```
Point intersect(Sphere sphere) {...}

Point intersect(Cube cube) {...}

Point intersect(Torus torus) {...}
```

etc

Problem is, since all of these classes inherit from Model, and the array is of type model, the elements will be of type model when they are accessed. There is no intersect for model, so I won't get a wrong-method error so much as a no-such-method error. So the issue is: how can I cast each member to its appropriate type?

Is there a reasonable way to do this, or must I try casting each subclass explicitly for each object, and using whatever sticks? This seems very hackish for what seems like a common problem.

Comment: If you have a class `Derived` which inherits from `Base`, any reason why you couldn't just do `Base::Foo()`?

Comment: The overloaded method is for a different class that takes objects of the supertype model. So a bunch of functions of the variety foo(bar [name]), foo(baz [name]), foo(biff [name]), etc, where bar, baz, and biff all inherit from the silly-b-words abstract superclass.

Comment: This is the classic "double dispatch" or "multiple dispatch" scenario. It's well documented and written about in the literature.

Comment: @Kerrek Thanks for the nomenclature tip! I'll look into it!

Comment: You could use *Visitor* pattern - i guess it is a kind of double dispatch mentioned earlier.

Comment: @alexm Oddly enough, I suggested a visitor pattern solution -- not that I knew that was what it was called -- and my girlfriend made a face, so I moved on. Now I've got some Gang-of-Four cred to the idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it the other way around. Instead of having the Ray with `Point intersect(Sphere sphere)` etc., each Model should have a function like: `virtual Point intersect(const Ray& ray) const`.

PS. as an aside, make sure your array is array of Model* or some form of smart pointer, otherwise you will be slicing your Models.

PPS. A real ray tracer would find a way to batch up their rays together, so you don't have so many (virtual) function calls.

**Edit:**

Also, it is possible to cast to a particular model, but using it in this case will ruin the OOP-ness, and result in an ugly switch statement. For example, suppose you have a `Model* model`, and you think it might be a `Sphere*`, then you can do: `Sphere* sphere = dynamic_cast<Sphere*>(model);`. If `model` was indeed a `Sphere*`, then `sphere` will now point to it, otherwise `sphere` will be `NULL`. IMO you should try to avoid using `dynamic_cast` in almost all situations; if you find that you must use it, it is usually a sign that your design messed up (redesign, or if you haven't time, learn from your mistakes).

Comment: Fair point about the bunching up, but this is just an assignment, and our first iteration of the design. Thanks for the tip re: pointers, and I arrived at the same conclusion you did re: the problem in general. Thanks!